# how can implement Right Arithmatic Shift in 8051 microcontroller only using RR A and RRC A?

Tags: shift, 8051

I want to implement Right Arithmatic Shift in 8051, only by using standard shift operators in this microcontroller. This means that, I want to implement right-arithmatic shift by only using RR A and RRC A.
can anyone have a suggenstion?

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since I did 8051, but I think you need:

```
mov C, ACC.7
rrc A
```

That is, pre-load carry with the sign bit of the accumulator, and then shift A right, and copy the carry (the old sign bit) into the new sign bit position.